# Get item using SELECT and WHERE

Tags: c#, linq, select, where-clause

I have an object of class TFNDailySummaryReport. Now I am trying to retrieve the value of AnsweredCalls on basis of AffiliateID. But I'm getting 
an IEnumerable type instead of string.

```
public class TFNDailySummaryReport
{
    public string AffiliateID { get; set; }
    public string AnsweredCalls { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what am I trying:

```
List<TFNDailySummaryReport> DealerTFNTable = dealerData;
string answeredCalls = DealerTFNTable.Where(d => d.AffiliateID == "1").Select(x => x.AnsweredCalls).ToString();
```

Comment: You are getting an `IEnumerable` because that's what `Select` returns. Now you need to decide what to with those. Do you only want to retain the `First` one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should select *a single* TFNDailySummaryReport - as the table theoretically may contain several - with an AffiliateID of "1":

```
List<TFNDailySummaryReport> DealerTFNTable = dealerData;
TFNDailySummaryReport theReport = DealerTFNTable.FirstOrDefault(d => d.AffiliateID == "1");
```

...and then access the AnsweredCalls property of this particular TFNDailySummaryReport:

```
if(theReport != null)
    string answeredCalls = theReport.AnsweredCalls;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<TFNDailySummaryReport> DealerTFNTable = dealerData;
string answeredCalls = DealerTFNTable.Where(d => d.AffiliateID == "1").FirstOrDefault().AnsweredCalls;
```

Note:
Make sure to check the null because FirstOrDefault() will return null if no matches found

Comment: Don't use `Where` followed by `FirstOrDefault`.  Instead use the overload of `FirstOrDefault` that takes the filtering delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Here DealerTFNTable is List means- DealerTFNTable is a list which can hold object of type TFNDailySummaryReport.

Your first where clause will return those objects whose AffiliateID is "1" as `Where(predicate)` extension method always returns `IEnumerable`.

Now you are selecting AnsweredCalls from the each object(returned by where extension method). So, again it is going to return IEnumerable of strings. In other word you have multiple string objects.

Now you are trying to convert these strings into string which will never give you the result which you want to see.
If you are so sure that you will get only one value in where condition, it's better to use `FirstOrDefault()` extension method.

Try this:

```
List<TFNDailySummaryReport> DealerTFNTable = dealerData;
string answeredCalls = DealerTFNTable.Where(d => d.AffiliateID == "1").Select(x => x.AnsweredCalls).FirstOrDefault();
```